# how to left align togglebuttons?

Tags: flutter

I have two togglebuttons inside a column, I'd like to second togglebutton to left align to the first toggleButtons, it works if all the button has the same size of text, here is the code, and you can see the image that second togglebuttons has more spaces in the left, any idea how to address this? here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: SampleStateless());
  }
}

class SampleStateless extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('sample')),
      body: mybody(),
    );
  }

  Widget mybody() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
          child: Text("Unicode Character Set:"),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
          child: ToggleButtons(
            isSelected: [false, true],
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(' Sample 1 '),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(' Sample 2'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
          child: Text("Show ABCD Wrting As ::"),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
          child: ToggleButtons(
            isSelected: [false, true],
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(' Sample 1 '),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(' ABC '),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: ` mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,` use this on the column, will will alght all children to the left

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, I added mainAxisALignment, it seems still not align properly, here is the updated gist: https://gist.github.com/sqllyw/863b30edd7bc28decaaf9ac210fc2d1c

Comment: i run your widget. you want them to be equal in width, right?

Comment: i want the 'sample1' button in the second line to left align with the 'sample1' in the first, here is the image that is not right: https://gist.github.com/sqllyw/863b30edd7bc28decaaf9ac210fc2d1c#gistcomment-3462920

Comment: you are putting the first ToggleButton inside Padding with `padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),` but not the second

Comment: good catch, thanks. i removed the padding, but still the same, code and image is here: https://gist.github.com/sqllyw/22547f61a222fb95720483c997777133

Comment: Wrap ToogleButtons in a Row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code and I set  `crossAxisAlignment` of column to `CrossAxisAlignment.start`. an then I added left padding for titles to left align to togglebuttons widgets like code below:

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  int _currentIndex;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('sample')),
      body: mybody(),
    );
  }

  Widget mybody() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0, left: 20.0),
          child: Text("Unicode Character Set:"),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
          child: ToggleButtons(
            isSelected: [false, true],
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(' Sample 1 '),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(' Sample 2'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0, left: 20.0),
          child: Text("Show ABCD Wrting As ::"),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
          child: ToggleButtons(
            isSelected: [false, true],
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(' Sample 1 '),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(' ABC '),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```